# How to create containers for Helix example

Tags: helix, docker

I'm trying to setup the code solution & the Sitecore instance in docker for a helix example, following this article.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore

After running the `docker-compose up -d`, it looks like it downloaded the images. I can see them in the Docker. But there are no containers.

I would like to see the Sitecore instance and the website to learn Headless development using ASP.NET Core Rendering SDK.

Should I manually create containers? Did the docker-compose step not run correctly?
How do I proceed from here.

**docker-compose up -d status:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

I have unchecked "User Docker Compose V2" and then ran again.
It now fails with this error:

> ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: failed to create
> endpoint basic-company-aspnetcore_traefik_1 on network
> basic-company-aspnetcore_default: failed during hnsCallRawResponse:
> hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process. (0x20) ERROR: Encountered errors
> while bringing up the project.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your first screenshot shows there are some errors. Can you please check that you're running Windows containers in Docker? Also, double check that 'Use Docker compose V2' is disabled in Docker settings.

Comment: @MiguelMinoldo Did that and ran compose command again. That seems to solve some issues but now it keeps failing with the traefik error.

Comment: Please check IIS is stopped in your host

Comment: try restart vmcompute service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping IIS worked for me.

These are the steps I had to do before following the instructions here:
https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore

#1 - run `smc -stop` in Run dialog to stop Symantec.
#2 - Then stop IIS in powershell with `iisreset /stop`.
#3 - Start Docker and uncheck `Use Docker Compose V2` in Settings. Apply the changes & Restart Docker.

Comment: Hi @Qwerty, glad to see it worked. Thanks for switching my comments as the answer to fix your issue.